# Custom form with Date textfield with jQuery popup

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm making a custom form and I would like to render a field that is just like the form that gets rendered for a Date with a jQuery Popup when editing a node.

[image]

I can't figure out how to build the array so that it will get rendered by drupal properly. I've tried a ton of different attempts, but this is what I've got currently:

```
$form['birthdate'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Offspring Birth Date"),
    '#id' => 'edit-field-filter-birthdate',
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#default_value' => '2015-01-01 10:30:00',
    '#date_type' => DATE_DATETIME,
    '#date_timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
    '#date_format' => 'm-d-Y H:i',
    '#date_increment' => 1,
    '#date_year_range' => '-3:+3',
);

$html = drupal_render($form);
```

The README.txt in the `date/date_popup` module says:

> To include a popup calendar in a form, use the type 'date_popup':
>
> $form['date'] = array(
>       '#type' => 'date_popup':
>       '#title => t('My Date'),
>       ....   );
>
> Set the #type to date_popup and fill the element #default_value with a
>   date adjusted to the proper local timezone, or leave it blank.

However, all that ever gets rendered is just the `'#title'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And the rest of the form elements render fine?

Comment: The rest of the function this is in generates the html directly (not using a render array). It wasn't written by me, just dealing with existing code. I'm trying to build an array just for this field and have drupal render it to html inside my function. Then I'll include that html with the rest of the html returned from this module function. That being said, yes, the rest of the page renders fine.. but it's not using a render array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the form with [`drupal_get_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/group/form_api/7):

```
$form = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_birthdate_form');
$html = drupal_render($form);

function MYMODULE_birthdate_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['birthdate'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    // ...
  );
  return $form
}
```

Comment: Perfect! You're the king.